# Django 1.9 No module named 'django.urls'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

Trying to install pcapdb on a fresh debian install (requires django==1.9) installed via 'sudo pip3 install django==1.9' Other parts of django can be imported without issue e.g. django.conf, django.db, django.utils, etc.

Output of 'pip3 list | grep -i django'

```
Django (1.9)
django-auth-ldap-ng (1.7.6)
django-braces (1.12.0)
django-celery (3.2.2)
django-filebrowser (3.9.1)
django-grappelli (2.10.2)
django-hosts (3.0)
django-url-tools (0.0.8)
djangorestframework (3.7.7)
djangorestframework-jwt (1.11.0)
```

pip3 --version

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

django version from interpreter

```
import django
print(django.get_version())
# 1.9
```

Ideas?

**Edit:**
The code in question is a dependency for pcapDB, not my code. See one of the files in question (django.urls imports) [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/compat.py)

Answer (score 1):

Try this line in **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

There is **no module name django.urls** in **before django2**, `urls` are present in **django.conf** package.

> Starting Django-2.0

`urls` are part of **django.urls**.

Comment: The code that references the module 'django.urls' isn't mine, but part of the package I am trying to install. Could you take a look at lines 15-24 of this file? https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/compat.py and advise?

Comment: @Felreava, there they have use **djang2.0** in that `urls` is part of **django.urls** but in earlier version and in `django-1.9` it is part of `django.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

In django 1.9 version or above until 1.11 version `url` module was in the `django.conf` package. 
In new release 2.0 version, it merged into **`django.url`**.
So now you can use **from django.urls import include, path, re_path** in your `URLconfs`.

for more info, you can check the release note.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#what-s-new-in-django-2-0